# Save the same variable with different value twice in a txt file - Batch

Tags: batch-file

So, i am new at batch programming and i had an idea.... the problem is that i want to save multiple values in a txt file with the same variable. To be more clear here is my code:

```
@echo off
cls
set /a "num=0"
:start

echo %num%
set /a "num=num+1"
echo %num% > text.txt
goto start
```

what i need is that every time the number gets bigger and saved the smaller numbers will remain saved... for example: now when %num% becomes "3" the number 3 will be saved in the text.txt file but it will replace the previous number. Is there any solution?

P.S. sorry for my bad english

Comment: to append to a file, use [>>](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the '>>' operator instead of '>'.

Comment: thank you very much i would apreciate it if you could explain to me the difference between ">" and ">>" because i cant find anything on the internet

Comment: @ThodorisThemelis see [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).